# iOS Center Text on Bottom

Tags: ios, text, label, vertical-alignment

I have a label that I create using the following way:

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:cell.contentView.bounds];
label.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
```

I would like to center the on the bottom of the label and center it horizontally.
I did not find any UITextAlignmentBottom in the typedef enums.

Can somebody suggest a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To 'align' the text to the bottom, you will want to make the UILabel the height of the text it needs to display - Google `UILabel sizeToFit`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "center the on the bottom of the label", but I'm thinking you might be asking about how to center a label at the bottom of the view controller that it's in. To do this, you will want to add some `NSLayoutConstraint`s to specify where in the window you want the label to go.

To do this programmatically, you will use `constraintWithItem:attribute:relatedBy:toItem:attribute:multiplier:constant:`. The "attribute" argument refers to `NSLayoutAttribute`, which can be set as `NSLayoutAttributeCenterX` when attempting to center the label, and `NSLayoutAttributeBottom` to specify the amount of space between the label and the bottom of the view controller.